# Output checkbox per user and save in plugin options

Tags: users, array, plugin-options

I am looking for a way to save my list of checkboxes as an array within the settings_fields of the plugin. I currently have:

```
<?php
   $WPusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=administrator' );
     foreach ( $WPusers as $user ) { ?>
       <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>[users]" id="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>-users" value="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" <?php checked( $user->ID, $options['users'], false ); ?> />
       <label for="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>[users<?php echo $user->ID; ?>]"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></label>
     <?php } ?>
```

The only thing is that it only saves one option instead of an array of all the checked boxes. I would love to see a way to store all the checked users within one option of the plugin.

Since I am new to WP development and PHP in general this is all quite new for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `[user]` to `[users][]`. Hope that will fix the problem. Now you'll get all the value in associative array within `[users]['your-checkbox-data-array']` So your code will be like-

```
<?php
   $WPusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=administrator' );
     foreach ( $WPusers as $user ) { ?>
       <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>[users][]" id="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>-users" value="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" <?php checked( $user->ID, $options['users'], false ); ?> />
       <label for="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>[users<?php echo $user->ID; ?>]"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></label>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! That was the way to do it! I updated the check function as well to check against the array.
`<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>[users][]" id="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>-users" value="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" <?php checked( ( in_array( $user->ID, $options['users'] ) ) ); ?> />
                <label for="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>[users<?php echo $user->ID; ?>]"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></label>`